# Printing JS multiplication table to the console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print a simple, unformatted multiplication table with JavaScript and I'm succeeding as long as I use the document.write() function. However, I cannot keep the same format when I'm trying to print the table to the console with console.log(). How should I go about it? My code is as follows:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   for(var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
       document.write(i*j) ;
   }
   document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: console.log prints to the console object. It does not parse HTML.

Comment: Depending on the browser you're working with, you may be able to use [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console.log not working same way as document.write, if you want formatting t console.log it depends on what you want, for output in table formating you can do this

```
var consoleFormat = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    consoleFormat[i] = []
    for(var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        document.write(i*j) ;
        consoleFormat[i].push(i*j)            
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
console.table(consoleFormat)
```

For output in array formatting you can do the same code only replace console.table for console.log

Look at the [docs of google chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks) for formatting ouput console, many the same features also apply for other browsers.